# Django form_valid() in CreateView not executing when trying to create a new dish object

Tags: python, django

In this code, the `form_valid()` function inside `DishCreateView` is not being executed when I try to create a new dish ie I am unable to create a new dish, when I click on create button page url not changes and remains the same. For detecting this I have put print statement inside `form_valid()` but this is not executed. Please help me out. Thanks

models.py

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes_pics')
    description = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.TextField(blank=True)
    required_time_to_cook = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
    cuisine_id = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dish-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
class DishCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Dish
    fields = ['name', 'image', 'description','required_time_to_cook','cuisine_id','user_id']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user
        print('self==========form==create=====',form)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

form_template.html

```html
{% extends "cookbook/base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
        Add Dish
      </legend>
      {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

dish_detail.html

```html
{% extends 'cookbook/base.html' %} 

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'cookbook/dish.css' %}">
<div class="media">
  <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ object.image.url }}">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading">{{ object.name }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ object.description }}</p>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ object.required_time_to_cook }}</p>
    <p class="text-secondary"> {{object.cuisine_id}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing i notice is that the name of the template is called form_template.html. Accourding the docs the createview uses a default suffix value for naming them template '_form' this in combination with you model name. So you should change your template name to:

```
from : form_template.html
to : dish_form.html
```

I think your view does not receive the data you post because the naming is not correct and  you didn't add an action value to the form. This should not be problem if the naming matches the view.

If this still not fixes your problem step 2 would be to add a

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
   print(form.errors)

to your view and put a print statement in there
this would give you the error back with the problem. so you know where the problem is.
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error  ValueError at /cookbook/dish/new/
The view cookbook.views.DishCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.What this means?